# realsense D415 sees curved floor

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, realsense

I have a realsense D415 cam mounted on the head of a robot.
The center of the cam is at 1525 mm above the floor and it is pointing to the floor in a 59 degree angle (that is the angle of the glass front of the cam with the floor).
I use the 1280x720 resolution of the cam and decimate the values by 3, ending up with 240 rows * 428 cols matrix.
I want to check for obstacles/abysses in the path of the robot.
Thought I could get Y (height) values of the floor by multiplying the distances from the depth_frame with the sine of the cam-rows and came up with this code:

```
decimate = rs.decimation_filter()
decimate.set_option(rs.option.filter_magnitude, 3)
depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
depth_frame = decimate.process(depth_frame)
depth = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data()).astype(np.float)
depth.shape = (240, 428)

topRowAngle = -59 + (42.5 / 2) # Vertical FOV of D415 is 42.5 deg
rowDeg = 42.5 / 240            # number of rows is 240
angle = topRowAngle
for row in range(240):
    rowSin = np.sin(np.radians(angle))
    floorY[row,:] = depth[row,:] * rowSin
    angle -= rowDeg
```

Plotting the result shows that I end up seeing a curved floor that prevents the robot to proceed. The floor is detected with a significant upward bump over the range of the rows where I expected a rather straight horizontal line.
[image: Y values of some of the coloms]
As I know the mounting height of the cam and that I look at a plain floor I thought of a correction factor for each point. The factors I ended up with are in the range .95 to 1.2.
As these correction factors enable me to "remove the floor range" and detect obstacles and abysses it looks a bit strange to me. Why should I need to correct the measured values of the cam?
Or am I wrong with my assumption that I can get the angle of the individual rows simply by dividing the vertical FOV by the number or rows?